# What is the difference between distutils.util.split_quoted and shlex.split

Tags: python, distutils, shlex

The python standard library provides [`distutils.util.split_quoted`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.util.split_quoted) and [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split).

Is there any situation in which `distutils.util.split_quoted(s)` gives a different result to `shlex.split(s)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**. These algorithms disagree about the definition of whitespace: `shlex` hardcodes the four characters [`' \t\r\n'`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Lib/shlex.py#L42), however `distutils` uses [`string.whitespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.whitespace) in [a regex](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Lib/distutils/util.py#L210). Therefore, it additionally considers some other characters as separators.

formfeed:

```
>>> distutils.util.split_quoted('A\fB')
['A', 'B']
>>> shlex.split('A\fB')
['A\x0cB']
```

vertical tab:

```
>>> distutils.util.split_quoted('A\vB')
['A', 'B']
>>> shlex.split('A\vB')
['A\x0bB']
```

Comment: Is one "more correct" than the other? For example, does posix specify a set of whitespace chars to be used as delimiters?

Comment: It's complicated. Posix says to respect the IFS variable (for example, you can actually set IFS to use commas and spaces, and then `python3 myscript.py a,b` will get `["myscript.py", "a", "b"]` in `sys.argv`. Should IFS be unset, then system uses spaces and tabs only - it should *not* field split on formfeed, vertical tab, nor even on carriage return (and I have verified this on a posix-compliant system of mine, indeed \r does not split words). So, I would say neither is strictly correct but `shlex.split` is perhaps the "more correct" of the two.